# How to initialize a generic base class in c++

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to rewrite some old code to make it more Object oriented. previously I have a **union** of *struct* called, say `Event`

```
union Event {
  AEvent aEvent;
  BEvent bEvent;
  CEvent cEvent;
}
```

and this `Event` is later used in a struct

```
struct EventImpl {
  ... //some other members 
  Event event();
}
```

now I am trying to use the powerful `shared_ptr`;
I created a new base class called `BaseEvent`

```
class BaseEvent{
    size_t m_TypeHash; 
    public: 
        using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<BaseEvent>;
        virtual ~EventDesc() = default; 
        
        template <class T>
        // cast to different events
        static std::shared_ptr<T> Cast(const Ptr& src) {
            return src->m_TypeHash == typeid(T).hash_code() 
                ? std::static_pointer_cast<T>(src)
                : nullptr;
        }
    protected: 
        BaseEvent(size_t typeHash) : m_TypeHash(typeHash){}
};
```

From here, `AEvent`, `BEvent` and `CEvent` can just extend `BaseEvent`, which makes the code cleaner.

But the question arises, what do I with the struct `EventImpl` that contains `Event`?? Is there a way to initialize a generic   `BaseEvent`?

```
struct EventImpl {
  ... //some other members 
  BaseEvent<T> event; //??
  T event; // ??
  std::shared_ptr<BaseEvent> event; // ???
}
```

**edit**:
the name `EventImpl` is a little misleading, as Dmitry pointed out, `EventWrapper` deems to be more appropriate. :)

Comment: Don't mix templates and inheritance.  Choose one or the other.

Comment: Templates are fine with inheritance when used properly.  What I'm confused about is "BaseEvent".  You define it as a class but then use it in EventImpl as if it were a template

Comment: @Joe, you are right, I intended to use class inheritance. I am still trying to pick up c++. :p

Comment: The common pattern is to have the `EventImpl` as a hidden implementation of the `Event`. You do the opposite.

Comment: @Joe Sorry, I should have said: don't mix templates and polymorphism.

Comment: modern union is [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (C++17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to do that. First of all you may use `std::variant` as a more OOP-aware alternative to the `union`:

```cpp
using Event = std::variant<AEvent, BEvent, CEvent>;
```

Another approach is to use dynamic polymorphism: you need to define a base class for all `XEvent` types:

```cpp
class BaseEvent {};

class AEvent : public BaseEvent {};
```

Another aspect of the dynamic polymorphism is how to return the value: by raw pointer, by reference, smart pointer, etc. The `std::shared_ptr` could be an overkill, the `std::unique_ptr` should be the first idiom to consider.

```cpp
struct EventWrapper {
  std::unique_ptr<Event> event();
};
```

I intentionally renamed the `EventImpl` to `EventWrapper` because if you use the `Impl` idiom, the opposite relation should be used:

```cpp
struct EventImpl;

class Event {
    std::unique_ptr<EventImpl> _impl;
};

class AEventImpl : public EventImpl {};
class BEventImpl : public EventImpl {};
class CEventImpl : public EventImpl {};
```

Comment: yeah, thank you Dmitry. I realized that the naming `EventImpl` probably is misleading. `EventWrapper` is what I meant.

Comment: and could you care to elaborate that why is `shared_ptr` an overkill? I thought I have multiple ptrs for the Event..?

Comment: The `shared_ptr` is slightly heavier than the `unique_ptr`. And you can always convert the unique to shared but not vice versa.